# how to charge later on Laravel Cashier new subscription?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier

When I create a new subscription on stripe using Laravel Cashier, that will charge the amount immediately. However, I want to create a new subscription without charging the amount and instead set a charge date manually. Is there any option to select the charge date?

```
Route::post('/user/subscribe', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->newSubscription(
        'default', 'price_monthly'
    )->create($request->paymentMethodId);
});
```

When a new subscription is created, the following events occur.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes Stripe has a [trial option](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials) you can use. But you need to ask Laravel Cashier for how to use that Stripe information within their API

Answer (score 0):

Only add function trialDays to object:

```
Route::post('/user/subscribe', function (Request $request) {
   $request->user()->newSubscription(
     'default', 'price_monthly'
   )->trialDays(30)->create($request->paymentMethodId);
});
```